# Is it ok to use wildcard CORS with a csrf token?

Tags: cors, csrf

I usually add * as the CORS allow origin header during development and wondered if I even have to change that if I use a csrf token to secure my site from forged requests.

Answer (score 0):

The base case for CSRF protection are requests that actually change something on the server. If it's just a GET that doesn't change stuff, you are good to go, because the same origin policy in browsers will not allow an attacker website to create requests to the original site (through a valid, logged on user's browser of course). So there is the same origin policy as protection for GETs.

**Until you add `access-control-allow-origin: *`.** With that, a malicious website can contain Javascript to download data from your service, and will be able to access the response - because you allowed it to.

Of course if there is something like a header-sent token authentication or similar so that this is not possible, then you are good to go. But the question was whether * in the CORS header is ok if you have the standard CSRF protection - and unfortunately it is not.

Comment: would it suffice if I would require the csrf token for get requests as well? (I am developing an api, so there will be no requests initiated by the user through a browser url directly)

Comment: Well, I would say mostly yes, but consider a few things. URL parameters get logged on the server and any proxy (and in the browser, but you're saying intended clients will not be browsers). It may be possible for an attacker to get hold of a valid token from these sources in a compound attack. If it's a user-seen URL, they tend to copy-paste (but again, not a valid point in your scenario). So in your case that would not be a huge risk I think, even though it sounds a bit strange to me. :) I know it destroys REST, but I would consider changing everything to POST if it's security critical.

Comment: Or even better, if the client is not a browser anyway, why not send the token as a request header? That's pretty standard, especially for APIs, and would work for pretty much any client, while being secure.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely not secure. You are circumventing the same origin policy.
A concrete example: You have a webshop and an endpoint to change a users bank account `http://mycoolwebshop/api/v1/users/3/changebankdata`
This endpoint can be called via an Ajax POST request. At every request, you are attaching the csrf token as HTTP header.

An attacker could forge a malicious request that is sent when the victim clicks a button on the attackers website:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            csrf_token = document.cookie.match("CSRF-TOKEN");
            csrf_token = csrf_token["input"].split("=")[1];
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://mycoolwebshop/api/v1/users/3/changebankdata",
            type:'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({ Bank-Account: "01234345" }),
            dataType: "json",
             headers: {
                "CSRF-TOKEN":csrf_token
                },
            success: function(){
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
                //alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<button></button>
```

The idea is here that the cookie is read from the browser's cookie store and attached as a custom HTML header.
However, this only works **if CORS allow origin is set to** * otherwise SOP [doesn't allow custom request headers from cross domains](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-custom-request-headers).